# Is an embedded Jetty Server guaranteed to be "ready for business" when the call to Server.start() returns?

Tags: java, jetty, embedding

I am having trouble finding any information about whether an embedded Jetty Server is guaranteed to be fully initialized and ready to receive requests when the call to Server.start() returns.

Nor have I been able to find anything conclusive by debugging.

If the server might still be initializing itself when the call returns, is there any way to register a callback so that I can be notified when it is indeed ready for action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, when returning from `Server.start()` the server is ready.

You can register a `LifeCycle.Listener` using `Server.addLifeCycleListener(listener)` to get notified of startup or shutdown events. If you look at the source of `Server.start()` you'll see, that it calls `Listener.lifeCycleStarted()` at the end.

Comment: Yes, I've studied the source and seen this. However, the event is pushed to any attached listeners just as the the server state is promoted to "STARTED", and the method returns. 

If the Servlets/resources are initialized and ready for work at that point is another question. By using breakpoints, I've been able to "freeze" at a state where Jetty will handle requests, but without initializing the servlets. 
I've not been able to figure out if it is possible for the server to remain in this state when the state is set to "STARTED", though.

Answer (score 1):

not a complete answer but maybe it depends on whether the servlets may or may not "load on startup"?

Comment: Good point. 
Would it be safe to assume that Jetty will have loaded/initialized them, if "load on startup" is enabled, when the method returns?